# Swift Package Manager - how to conditionally link platform to iOS only?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, google-mobile-ads

I have an iOS app using the GoogleMobileAds Swift package and I would like to add a tvOS destination to my target. I added that through the supported destinations:
[image: adding tvOS destination]

Because GoogleMobileAds does not support tvOS, I would like to remove the library link when I build for tvOS. Under my target's "Build Phases" tab I opened up the "Link Binary With Libraries" and set the GoogleMobileAds library to be filtered for iOS only
[image]

My understanding is this prevents the linking of the library when built for tvOS. However, that doesn't seem to be the case? When I try building I get the following error:

> **While building for tvOS Simulator, no library for this platform was found in** '/Users/{myHomeDir}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{myPackageName}-bubgtznikupuivcjetnfyqxleoiu/SourcePackages/artifacts/**swift-package-manager-google-mobile-ads/GoogleMobileAds.xcframework**'.

Building for iOS works just fine. Also, in my code, I've wrapped any imports to the library around platform conditionals as such:

```
#if os(iOS)
import GoogleMobileAds
#endif
```

I've tried everything I can think of and can't seem to figure this one out! How can I build for tvOS without having to create a new target? I thought that was the whole idea of the conditional platforms.

EDIT - I've tried switching to

```
#if canImport(GoogleMobileAds)
```

but the same error still appears.

Comment: Sorry. Apart from the `#if canImport()` part I don't see anything else that would help. Everything else seem to be correct. Could this be an Xcode bug? Or maybe the GoogleMobileAds framework is not build with multi-platform project in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's advice is this:

```
#if canImport(GoogleMobileAds)
import GoogleMobileAds
#endif
```

As documented here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-a-multiplatform-app-target

Comment: Good catch! I didn't see that before. I've updated my imports but the error is still appearing. :(